# Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class mtsts

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to render a ggplot graph within shiny using the code below

```
    selectInput(inputId = "teamA", label = "Pick team A",choices = odiTeam$Team,selected =1)
selectInput(inputId = "teamB", label = "Pick team B",choices = odiTeam$Team,selected =3)


odiTeamAvB<-reactive({
  filter(odiTeamAgg,(odiTeamAgg$Team == input$teamA & odiTeamAgg$Opposition == input$teamB) |(odiTeamAgg$Team == input$teamA & odiTeamAgg$Opposition == input$teamB))
              })

renderPlot({
ggplot(data=odiTeamAvB(),aes(x=Team,y=Result))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())+theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  labs(y="Wins")
}, height = 300)
```

I keep getting Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class mtsts
tried different combinations, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried `ggplot(data=   as.data.frame( odiTeamAvB() ), ..)`

Comment: I did now and get a new errors now, this is what I am doing 
` ggplot(data=as.data.frame(odiTeamAvB()),aes(x=odiTeamAvB$Team,y=odiTeamAvB$Result))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())+theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  labs(y="Wins")
}, height = 300) `

now I get object 'odiTeamAvB' not found or function 'odiTeamAvB()' not found or if I use nothing i just get object 'Team' not found.

Comment: it would be helpful to have a reproducable example of your shiny and maybe a few rows of your data using dput().

Comment: Output from dput(odiTeamAvB)  

`## structure(function () `  
`## {`  
`##     .dependents$register()`  
`##     if (.invalidated || .running) {`  
`##         self$.updateValue()`  
`##     }`  
`##     .graphDependsOnId(getCurrentContext()$id, .mostRecentCtxId)`  
`##     if (identical(class(.value), "try-error")) `  
`##         stop(attr(.value, "condition"))`  
`##     if (.visible) `  
`##         .value`  
`##     else invisible(.value)`  
`## }, observable = <environment>, class = "reactive")`